# How to use a macro variable in a where clause in proc sql

Tags: sql, sas

For example, I have:

```
%let state_exclude = Michigan Maine Minnesota;
proq sql;
   create table States
   select state
   from geography_dim as geo
   where geo.country="US" and geo.state ~= "&state_exclude"
quit;
```

It returns zero rows, I think it is because how I used the macro variable there but I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not America people, is "Michigan Maine Minnesota" three independent place? If so, you should use `in` operator rather than `=`. For example:

```
%let state_exclude = "Michigan" "Maine" "Minnesota"; 
proq sql; 
  create table States as
  select state from geography_dim
  where country="US" and state not in (&state_exclude);
quit;
```